# Making black parts of an image transparent opencv in Android

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin, image-processing

I am currently trying to use edge detection to find edges and then converting the remaining picture from black to transparent. I have created 4 different channels and have used `Imgproc.threshold` to make an alpha channel with complete transparency. After this, I have attempted to merge all 4 channels into one but the resulting image still shows up with a black background. (I know this black background isn't transparent since I have layered the resulting image on top of my camerax preview).

```
    private fun detectEdges(image: Bitmap) {

    val src = Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4)
    Utils.bitmapToMat(image, src)
    val edges = Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1)
    
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, edges, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
    Imgproc.Canny(edges, edges, 80.0, 100.0)
    
    val src1 = edges.clone()
    val src2 = edges.clone()
    val alpha = Mat(image.height, image.width, CvType.CV_8UC1)
    
    Imgproc.threshold(edges, alpha, 70.0, 0.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    val dst = Mat()
    val listMat = listOf(edges, src1, src2, alpha)
    Core.merge(listMat, dst)

    val output =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    Utils.matToBitmap(dst, output)

    BitmapHelper.showBitmap(safeContext, output, binding.edgeDetectionView)
}
```

Any ideas on how to make the image transparent?